# Parse XML Notification from Amazon SQS in java?

Tags: java, xml, amazon-sqs

**Context:**

I get notifications from `MWS` into `SQS`. I want to listen to queue and process messages for retrieving information.

Example of notification:

```
<Notification>
<NotificationMetaData>
    <NotificationType>ReportProcessingFinishedNotification</NotificationType>
    <PayloadVersion>1.0</PayloadVersion>
    <UniqueId>rwf00-dvSDC-DFAB-sd3frw</UniqueId>
    <PublishTime>2019-03-05T12:55:08.965Z</PublishTime>
    <SellerId>111111</SellerId>
</NotificationMetaData>
<NotificationPayload>
    <ReportProcessingFinishedNotification>
        <SellerId>111111</SellerId>
        <ReportRequestId>11111111111</ReportRequestId>

        <ReportType>_GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_REMOVAL_ORDER_DETAIL_DATA_</ReportType>
        <ReportProcessingStatus>DONE_NO_DATA</ReportProcessingStatus>
    </ReportProcessingFinishedNotification>
</NotificationPayload>
</Notification>
```

**Question:**

At the moment, I am listening for the queue as follows:

```
@SqsListener(value = "notification-test-queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void processSubscription(String xmlNotification) { /*TODO: Some action in here*/}
```

How to properly parse `xmlNotification`? The main problem that all parser expect to get `xml` identifier with link on top. I experimented with `JAXB` and `DOMParser`. I also tried studying [examples from Github](https://github.com/sauravpd/java-xml-parser-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/XMLParser/JAXB/Employee.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the library that worked with the structure of my document out of the box [Jcabi-xml](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-xml).